# Querying Windows Event Logs Remotely (Linux)

Tags: windows, linux, wmi, rpc, event-log

Right now I have a Java application running WMI querying event logs, this is *painfully* slow due to the nature of WMI (ok, not painfully, but it may not be able to keep up with our domain controller), and dllhost.exe gets hammered serving up WMI requests and remote DCOM objects, pretty unnecessary just to read logs.

The next bit of exploration is in Windows RPC calls, but I'm confused... is the Windows RPC implementation (sorta kinda not wonderfully documented for event logs) just another name for WMI? Or will I be receiving raw event log information?

Other than these two methods, does anyone know of any other ways to hook into the event log creation event so I can have the servers automatically push their logs to me? It would be nice if it was something that could be fairly easily implemented in Linux, but I can tamper with WINE and Mono if I have to...

Or would it probably be best to write and deploy scripts on all the servers and have them push it to my program on the Linux box (though now I have to worry about the uptime of all those scripts)?

Or better yet... should I just write a Java service that can plug into the event logs natively and install those on the various windows machines and have it hand off the logs to my central Linux box that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jarapac](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jarapac/) looks promoising, I'm going to dig a little bit at this and see if Windows RPC performance is up to par and how hard it is to implement.  If it's fairly straight forward: Yay! Windows RPC on Linux.

If not, it's simply not possible without your own implementation. :(

Comment: Have you had any luck ?